# Oracle - Dynamic queries using variables in select into and where

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I'm trying to build dynamic SQL selecting a value into a variable and using a variable in the where clause.  My syntax is incorrect, but I'm not familiar with the subtleties of Oracle syntax.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE

v_strWorkstationOld varchar(40) := 'hostname1';
v_strWorkstationNew varchar(40) := 'hostname2';

v_intnumOld int := 0;
v_intnumNew int := 0;
v_sql varchar(800);

BEGIN

IF ((v_strWorkstationOld = '') OR (v_strWorkstationNew = '')) THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Workstation must have a value.  Please update the value in the script and run it again.');
ELSE

  v_sql := 'SELECT num INTO v_intnumOld FROM hsi.hostnametable WHERE name = ''' || v_strWorkstationOld || '''';
  --dbms_output.put_line (v_sql);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (v_sql);

  IF ((v_intnumOld > 0) AND (v_intnumNew > 0)) THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('Found for Workstation:  ' || v_strWorkstationNew);
  ELSE  
    dbms_output.put_line('No registernum found for Workstation:  ' || v_strWorkstationNew);
  END IF;

END IF;

dbms_output.put_line('COMMIT;');
COMMIT;

END;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL for this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use dynamic SQL for this, it's a straightforward `select into` clause:

```
...
ELSE

  SELECT num INTO v_intnumOld
  FROM hsi.hostnametable
  WHERE name = v_strWorkstationOld;

  IF ((v_intnumOld > 0) AND (v_intnumNew > 0)) THEN
...
```

If you had a more complicated scenario that did actually warrant dynamic SQL, you would use a bind variable rather than concatenating the variable value, and then the syntax would be something like:

```
  v_sql := 'SELECT num FROM hsi.hostnametable WHERE name = :b0';
  --dbms_output.put_line (v_sql);
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_intnumOld USING v_strWorkstationOld;
```

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#LNPLS01115):

> - If the dynamic SQL statement is a SELECT statement that can return at most one row, put out-bind variables (defines) in the INTO clause and in-bind variables in the USING clause.

... and [this example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BJEIJEBJ).

But don't do that for your example code, use static SQL.

---

This also won't do what you think:

```
IF ((v_strWorkstationOld = '') OR (v_strWorkstationNew = '')) THEN
```

An empty string, `''`, is the same as `null` in Oracle, and you can't use equality operators to check for null. You'd need to use `is null` instead:

```
IF (v_strWorkstationOld IS NULL OR v_strWorkstationNew IS NULL) THEN
```

although since you give both variables values when they're declared, neither can be null anyway. You also aren't ever doing anything to change `v_intnumNew` from its default value of zero, or to change `v_strWorkstationNew`. And you don't need to commit after a query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed response.  That does make sense and I did try that first.  The odd part is that if I do a straight SELECT INTO, I get the following error "ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 21.  01403. 00000 -  "no data found".  If I do a simple SELECT (without the INTO), I get a single row in return (SELECT num FROM hsi.hostnamtable WHERE name = v_strWorkstationOld;).

Comment: @Pheathers - well, querying dynamically wouldn't change that error. Do you have a (committed) record in that table which exactly matches `hostname1`, including the case and trailing whitespace, say? Not quite sure what your comment edit meant - you seem to still get the 1403 error, and you can't use the variable in plain SQL. Can you see that single record in a different session - where you inserted it but didn't commit, perhaps?

Comment: Most likely I have trailing white space.  Question, when you use a variable in a WHERE is there a way to use a wildcard?  (ie v_stWorkstationOld || '%' or something like that?  Is that needed?)

Comment: You could use `LIKE v_stWorkstationOld || '%'`, but that would match, say, `hostname10` too. You could use a regular expression to look just for whitespace but that's getting complicated. It would be better to eliminate the trailing whitespace if you can. Also check if your table column is also `varchar2`, or is maybe `char`?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Currently I'm not using the ...New variables, but they will be used in time.  I simplified the script to hopefully clarify the question.  The name column is a char(80), so white space could be a problem.  Since the variable is getting declared and assigned the exact value which I'm looking for I would think that using a LIKE in the WHERE should work, however I still don't get any results, only the "no data found".  The data has been committed and that should not be an issue.

Comment: What if you declare `v_strWorkstationOld` as `char(80)` too? Or more generally as `hsi.hostnamtable.name%TYPE` to avoid mistakes and handle future changes automatically. There is usually no good reason to use `char` though, it's almost always much better to use `varchar2` for your table columns.

Comment: Awesome!!!  That did it!  I used the column type in the declaration and it worked.  Thanks you for your time.  I was banging my head on this one.